# Multiple Views In Xcode Swift Playground

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift-playground

I am creating a swift playground I want to create multiple views, first an introduction screen then a SpriteKit game then a conclusion screen.
How can I change between views in Xcode playground.

[Here is a picture that show first and 2 and 3 view in sources that I want to display by order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcXUr.png)

How can I change views between these 3 files and there is no storyboard. What code should I put in MyPlayground.

Comment: Create a demo project in xcode instead of playground.

Comment: My project is to create a playground not a project. @dahiya_boy

Comment: Can't you just set the `liveView` property of `PlaygroundPage.current`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your playground file, you create your scene view like this:

```
let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 640, height: 480))
let myScene = FirstView(fileNamed: "MyPlayground")

if let scene = myScene {
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
    sceneView.presentScene(scene)
}

PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView
```

And in your First View file, create your `FirstView` class. Do not forget to put it as public:

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

public class FirstView: SKScene {

    private var label : SKLabelNode!

    open override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Get label node from scene and store it for use later
        label = SKLabelNode(text: "first view")
        label.position = view.center
        addChild(label)
    }
}
```